# Can Brother ADS 2000 scanner be used in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: scanner

Brother doesn't list a driver for this scanner. Is there one somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Brother provide a Linux driver for this on their website in RPM and Debian variants for 32-bit and 64-bit:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_scn.html#brscan4_ads

They also provide installation instructions for Linux:

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1d.html

That said, Linux itself contains support for thousands of hardware products built-in, often even when the hardware vendor doesn't (for example, sometimes open source developers will have written their own alternative driver).

I would encourage you to see if you can use it without installing the hardware vendor's driver first, just to see if a built-in driver in Linux will handle it.  If so, that'll be a cleaner solution for you.

Often, the drivers supplied in Linux will be open-source and maintained while drivers supplied by manufacturers may be closed-source and dated.  That said, often there is no existing open-source driver for a piece of hardware.  And sometimes the manufacturer themselves made their driver open-source and so a derivative of that appears in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the driver from:

If you are running 32bit: [here](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan4-0.4.2-1.i386.deb&lang=English_lpr)

If you are running 64bit: [here](http://www.brother.com/cgi-bin/agreement/agreement.cgi?dlfile=http://www.brother.com/pub/bsc/linux/dlf/brscan4-0.4.2-1.amd64.deb&lang=English_lpr)

Press `I Accept` and wait to finish download.

Now to install the driver:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i brscan*.deb
```

Install the [udev rule setup](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/instruction_scn1c.html#u13.04).

If you need to debug, then run:

```
/opt/brother/scanner/brscan4/brsaneconfig4 -d
```